# Sorting in Elastic Search, using nested object type

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am trying to get data using elastic search in a python program. Currently I am getting the following data from an elastic search request. I wish to sort the data on rank:type. For example i want to sort data by raw_freq or maybe by score.
What should the query look like?
I believe it will be something using nested query. Help would be very much appreciated.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "customer_id": 108,
            "id": "Qrkz-2QBigkG_fmtME8z",
            "rank": [
                {
                    "type": "raw_freq",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "type": "score",
                    "value": 3
                },
                {
                    "type": "pmiii",
                    "value": 1.584962
                }
            ],
            "status": "pending",
            "value": "testingFreq2"
        },

                ],

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how you can sort your data:

```
"query": {
  "term": {"status": "pending"}
},
"sort": [
  {"rank.type.keyword": {"order" : "desc"}}
]
```

Comment: @Arpit What are the output and expected results?